# remove default dialog area in swt dialog

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface

I have a class which is extending `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog` class. I have created a custom dialog so need to remove its defult OK cancle button for this i override a super class method to do this as follow.

```
protected Button createButton(Composite arg0, int arg1, String arg2, boolean arg3) 
{
        //Retrun null so that no default buttons like 'OK' and 'Cancel' will be created
        return null;
}
```

All is fine, Now i observe that after removing OK cancle button there is a default area left in shell.

That I tried a lot but not getting removed, all changes i am doing reflecting above to this.
So please tell me what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding `createButton()`, you can override `createButtonBar()` and simply return `null`, then you don't have the empty button bar at the bottom of the dialog:

```
@Override
protected Control createButtonBar(Composite parent)
{
    /* You don't want a button bar, so just return null */
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect in my case.

```
@Override
protected Control createButtonBar(Composite parent)
{
    /* You don't want a button bar, so just return null */
    parent.dispose();
    return null;
}
```